# WooCommerce - Different downloads for customers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am opening a shop, and i will be selling products that users will be downloading
Once purchased, the product can only be used by ONE person, and i was wondering instead of having the same product for every purchase is it possible to have different ones, as this would really benefit me. (unique download per customer)
Thanks.

Comment: If you have 100 different products and 100 customers that's easy. If you have only 1 product that you somehow want to make unique for each customer you will need to provide more information. Would a unique link per customer that they can only download once be sufficient? Are you able to disclose what the product is (or what kind or product - ebook, software, other digital download etc)? Do you need to somehow edit the product itself to make it unique for each customer? Those are just a few points that would help you get a good answer to your question. Good luck finding the answer!